# Logback access events not capturing response content

Tags: logback, graphql-java, spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder, spring-graphql

We are developing a new service using `Spring Boot` and `Spring for GraphQL`. We want to enable `logback` access logs to capture both request and response headers and content. I have configured logback access logs but it's only working for the request headers and content but **`response content is always empty`**

`application.yaml`

```
logback:
  access:
    enabled: true
    config: classpath:logback/logback-access.xml
    useServerPortInsteadOfLocalPort: true
    tee-filter:
      enabled: true
  tomcat:
    enableRequestAttributes: true
```

`logback-access.xml`

```
<configuration>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%fullRequest%n%n%fullResponse</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
```

`TeeFilter` config: I have tried with order range `[-1,0,1,9999,-9999]`

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<TeeFilter> someFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<TeeFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new TeeFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setName("TeeFilter");
    registrationBean.setOrder(-1);

    return registrationBean;
}
```

and sample console output is

```
POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json, multipart/mixed
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
authorization: xxxx
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 253
content-type: application/json
cookie: Idea-89db1df9=f548ac74-ebc1-4a6a-b686-1517cf9a6c8b; JSESSIONID=B6F9566795FF0216864B7D37F70FF61D

{"query":"xxxx"}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 12 Oct 2023 08:52:42 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

This request has graphql response content but log cannot capture it. Why log configuration only capturing request content but not response ? It's strange because exact the same configuration working for our our another Spring Boot Rest service. Is it somehow related to the `Spring for Graphql` or `Graphql for Java` ?

Comment: it's hard to help you without knowing what the filter implementation looks like.

Comment: @BrianClozel thx for the interest: TeeFilter  is provided by logback team to capture ad the Req/Res. https://logback.qos.ch/recipes/captureHttp.html#capturing

Comment: I think problem is the reactive/async nature of the request execution in `Spring Boot for GraphQL` where response is written to request object later when Filter chain existed  : " The Spring MVC asynchronous support is built around that mechanism. When a controller returns a DeferredResult, the Filter-Servlet chain is exited, and the Servlet container thread is released. " https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-ann-async.html

Comment: is the filter registration configured for async dispatch?

Comment: @BrianClozel I have configured the filter bean extenstion as you suggested :`registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR );` but now it's missing request content :)

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors, I have found a solution that may be not the optimal one. I disabled `TeeFilter` and registered two filters: one for `DispatcherType.ASYNC` to capture response content and another for `DispatcherType.REQUEST` to capture request content.

`Configuration` for filter registration

```
@Configuration
public class LoggingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ResponseContentCaptureFilter> responseContentCaptureFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ResponseContentCaptureFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new ResponseContentCaptureFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/graphql");
        registrationBean.setName("ResponseContentCaptureFilter");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
        registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.ASYNC);

        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestContentCaptureFilter> requestContentCaptureFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<RequestContentCaptureFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new RequestContentCaptureFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/graphql");
        registrationBean.setName("RequestContentCaptureFilter");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST);

        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

and filters: `ResponseContentCaptureFilter`

```
import static ch.qos.logback.access.AccessConstants.LB_OUTPUT_BUFFER;

@Slf4j
public class ResponseContentCaptureFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper cashedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

        chain.doFilter(request, cashedResponse);

        request.setAttribute(LB_OUTPUT_BUFFER, cashedResponse.getContentAsByteArray());

        cashedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
}
```

`RequestContentCaptureFilter`

```
import static ch.qos.logback.access.AccessConstants.LB_INPUT_BUFFER;

@Slf4j
public class RequestContentCaptureFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper cachedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);

        chain.doFilter(cachedRequest, response);

        cachedRequest.setAttribute(LB_INPUT_BUFFER, cachedRequest.getContentAsByteArray());
    }
}
```

This approach has a drawback as it breaks the testing integration of Spring Boot for GraphQL, causing the request execution to fail in tests.